# Basic Currency Converter not working with most currencies

Tags: c++

So im new to coding in general and im making a currency converter (aka if statement mania for a noobie) and I made it so you can select for ex Usd to Euro and it should only show the what x amount of Usd is worth in euro but its only working for Usd to pound and its no diffrent from all the other statements so why is that the only one that works the program was built in c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

    string Euro = "Euro";
    string Usd = "Usd";
    string Pound = "Pound";
    string Peso = "Peso";

    string s;

    string c;

    // basically what s equals
    float a;

    // basically what c equals
    float b;


    cout << "What type of currency do you want to convert: Usd,Euro,Pound,Peso " << endl;

    cin >> s;
    
    cout << "Now select what you would like to convert it to " << endl;

    cin >> c;

    cout << "How much " << s << " do you have " << endl;

    cin >> a;

    // Euro to everything
    if(s <= Euro) 
    {
        
        if (c <= Usd) {
            b = a * 1.02;

            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of dollars" << endl;
        }

        if (c <= Pound) {
            b = a * .85;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pounds" << endl;
        }

        if (c <= Peso) {
            b = a * 131.82;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pesos" << endl;
        }

    }
    // Usd to everything
    
    if (s <= Usd) 
    {


        if (c <= Euro) {
            b = a / 1.02;

            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Euros" << endl;
        }

        if (c <= Pound) {
            b = a/ 1.2;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pounds" << endl;
        }
        if (c <= Peso) {
            b = a * 129.07;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pesos" << endl;
        }

    }

    // Pound to everything
    if (s <= Pound) 
    {


        if (c <=Usd) {
            b = a *1.2;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of dollars" << endl;
        }
        if (c <= Euro) {
            b = a * 1.18;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Euros" << endl;
        }
        if (c <= Peso) {
            b = a * 154.92;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pesos" << endl;
        }
    }
    // Peso to everythinhg
    if (s <= Peso) 
    {

        if (c <= Usd) {
            b = a * .0077;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of dollars" << endl;
        }

        if (c <= Pound) {
            b = a * .0065;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Pounds" << endl;
        }

        if (c <= Euro) {
            b = a * .0076;
            cout << "You would have " << b << " amount of Euros" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `<=` is very unusual to see in string comparisons. Make sure it describes the behaviour you want the program to have.

Comment: `s <= Euro` does not do what you think it does. It does the same thing it does in numerical expressions, but with text string. Was that your intention? For example, `"Abracadabra" <= "Euro"` is true, in C++, does that make sense to you?

Comment: Recommendation: Give variables names that describe what they represent and avoid single letter variables. I've pulled too many bugs out of code over the years where someone accidentally swapped `i` and `j` or  `d` and `b`. If you're implementing a formula that uses single letters, use the same notation as the formula, but most other places use identifiers that allow you to spot mistakes more easily.

Comment: `void main()` -- No.  `int main()`.

Comment: I suspect you want to replace your usage of `<=` with `==`.  Also, your code doesn't handle the identity conversion: Converting dollars to dollars (or any currency with itself) should have an exchange rate of 1.0.  And now the challenge: Can you reduce and simplify the code that comes after the last `cin` statement to only have a single `cout` ?statement.

Comment: Why not build a `std::unordered_map` of currency identifiers to their relative rate? `unordered_map<string, double> rates = {{"USD", 1.02}, {"GBP", 0.85}, {"MXN", 132.82}};` -- now just do table lookups to find the rate for any currency. You can extend as required, to get "friendly names" for the currency IDs also. This way you can convert from one currency to any other currency going via your reference currency (EUR), and only have one calculation to do it with one table of rates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in trying to compress this into as simple a process and cut down on possibly going on tangents with various if/else comparison, feel free to parse and dissect this example I put together.  The premise here in streamlining the conversion from one currency to another is to choose one of the currencies as a base.  In this scenario, I chose the EURO as the base from which to convert to and from.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define USD 0.980392
#define GBP 1.176471
#define ESP 0.007586

int main()
{
    string src, target;
    float amount, converted, to_euro, from_euro;

    cout << "What type of currency do you want to convert: Usd,Euro,Pound,Peso " << endl;

    cin >> src;

    cout << "Now select what you would like to convert it to " << endl;

    cin >> target;

    cout << "How much " << src << " do you have " << endl;

    cin >> amount;

    if (src.compare("Usd") == 0)            /* Derive source currency to Euro conversion rate */
        to_euro = USD;
    else
        if (src.compare("Pound") == 0)
            to_euro = GBP;
        else
            if (src.compare("Peso") == 0)
                to_euro = ESP;
            else
                to_euro = 1.00;             /* Default when source is EURO */

    if (target.compare("Usd") == 0)         /* Derive Euro to target currency conversion rate */
        from_euro = 1.00 / USD;
    else
        if (target.compare("Pound") == 0)
            from_euro = 1.00 / GBP;
        else
            if (target.compare("Peso") == 0)
                from_euro = 1.00 / ESP;
            else
                from_euro = 1.00;         /* Default when target is EURO */

    converted = amount * to_euro * from_euro;

    cout << "The converted amount is to: " << converted << " " << target << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Converting the source currency into the equivalent value in Euros and then converting from Euros to the target currency cuts down on the "if/else" testing needed.  Probably if one were wanting to make this a bit more practical one would read in the monetary rates from a file.  But this should provide a proof of principle test.